# What is the equivalent of "!=" in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, function, syntax, inequality

The problem is that `!=` does not work as a function in excel vba.

I want to be able to use

`If strTest != "" Then` instead of `If strTest = "" Then`

Is there another approach to do this besides `!=`?

My function to mimic `!=` is

```
Sub test()

Dim intTest As Integer
Dim strTest As String

intTest = 5

strTest = CStr(intTest) ' convert

Range("A" + strTest) = "5"



    For i = 1 To 10
        Cells(i, 1) = i

        If strTest = "" Then
            Cells(i, 1) = i
        End If

    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `!=` and not `<>`?

Comment: What is your question? Why `!=` doesn't work in vba, or what is the inequality operator in vba?

Comment: http://duckduckgo.com/?q=VBA+comparison+operators

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Because the inequality operator in VBA is `<>`

```
If strTest <> "" Then
    .....
```

the operator `!=` is used in C#, C++.

Answer (score 29):

In VBA, the `!=` operator is the `Not` operator, like this:

```
If Not strTest = "" Then ...
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `Not` is the logical inversion operator, which corresponds to `!` in C-style languages.

Answer (score 7):

Just a note. If you want to compare a string with  `""` ,in your case,  use

```
If LEN(str) > 0 Then
```

or even just

```
If LEN(str) Then
```

instead.

Comment: I know to people somewhat new to VBA, this answer may seem weird, but this, believe it or not, is FAR more efficient than checking against `<> ""`

Comment: Fun fact to back this answer: Visual Basic and Pascal languages store strings with their length in the beginning and the content itself right after that. C-based and Java languages, on the other hand, do not store the length and have the '\0' (null) terminator to signal that the string ended. Because of that, getting the length in VBA is fast -- it's just reading an integer from memory -- and is slow in Java -- you need to iterate through the string.

Comment: @LimaNightHawk *far* more efficient? Can you elaborate on that please? I guess that most modern compilers would catch the pattern `<> ""` and produce the same p-code as `Len(str)`.

Comment: @Roland This has to do with how VBA stores strings in memory. I'll let you Google for a fuller explanation, but in short, part of how strings are stored is that the first bytes store the length of the string, then the following bytes store the characters: `[3][C][A][T]`. An "empty" string has a `[0]` for the first bytes and checking the `Len` allows the code to just check and compare Integers. Additionally, when you do a `= ""` that second `""` has to be allocated as its own string first in memory, then compared to your target string.

Comment: @Roland: That would be an easy optimization, but, apparently, the VBA compiler does not do it. [Someone did a benchmark](https://roymacleanvba.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/performance-strings/) with the result that `Len(str) > 0` is about twice as fast as `str <> ""` for 10 million iterations. That said, we are talking about *extreme* micro-optimization here (0.36 vs 0.72 seconds for 10 million iterations), so I'll definitely stick with the more readable `str <> ""`.

Comment: @Heinzi ,I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to  use `<>` instead of `!=`.